Moving data for points on ArcGIS
I am working on a project to show the traffic flow on the US-Mexico Border Entry Points. I have the latitude and longitude points and they are mapped on ArcGIS pro. However, I have the traffic flow value (one column) from 2019 to 2024 for different ports and I want to include a time lapse, showing the circles enlarged or getting smaller according to the values and I cannot figure out how to do so.
enter image description here
While I have mapped the coordinates using the xycoordinates tool and created a timelapse, the size of the circles mapped are remaining the same throughout.
Can you please if this is the correct way to do so and if I am doing something incorrectly? Or is it possible in the first place at all? Thanks for your help!

Ensure Your Data is Properly Structured
Your data should include the following:
Latitude and longitude coordinates for the ports (already done).
A time field indicating the year (or exact time period) of the data.
Traffic flow values for each port and year.
Create a Time-Enabled Layer. In ArcGIS Pro, right-click on your feature layer and choose Properties.
Navigate to the Time tab.
Enable Time and configure it to use the time field in your data.
Use Graduated Symbols for Circle Sizes .Open the Symbology pane for your layer.
Choose Graduated Symbols as the symbology type.
Set the traffic flow value field (e.g., TrafficFlow) as the value field.
Define the size range for the circles based on the range of your traffic flow data. Dynamic Circle Size Changes Over Time. Ensure that the time field is enabled as described in Step 2.
The time-enabled layer will now animate based on the time field, and the graduated symbol sizes will adjust according to the traffic flow values for the respective time period.
Configure the Time Slider. Open the Time Slider tool in ArcGIS Pro.
Use the slider to configure how the animation progresses (e.g., interval, playback speed).
Preview the animation to ensure the circles grow/shrink as expected over time.
Export the Time-Lapse Animation
Once satisfied with the animation, go to the View tab and select Animation.
Use the Animation Timeline to refine playback.
Export the animation as a video or GIF to share your results.
Common Issues to Check:
Ensure the Traffic Flow column is numeric and correctly linked to each year.
Confirm that the symbology is set to dynamically scale based on the traffic flow field.
Verify that the time field is properly formatted.
If you follow these steps and your circles still don't change size, double-check that the traffic flow data is properly linked to the time periods.
The graduated symbol ranges match the range of your data.

This worked perfectly! Thank you so much for your help Srayansh! I am new to ArcGIS and had been stuck on this for a while so really appreciate your help.

Where did you copy this from though? You have to give proper credit/attribution.
